# netstat: n: unknown or uninstrumented protocol

Tags: terminal, unix

I always use netstat on ubuntu to check which processes are listening on specific ports. I use the following switches with netstat that work fine on ubuntu but on mac fail:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
netstat: n: unknown or uninstrumented protocol
```

Comment: -p requires a protocol `man netstat`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Linux's `netstat` command options and OS X(/BSD)'s have almost nothing to do with each other. Of the options you're invoking, only `-n` means the same on both, and some of the others (`-l` and `-p`) have no equivalent on OS X's `netstat`. What I habitually use on OS X is `netstat -an | grep LISTEN`, but that doesn't show UDP or the program involved. I suppose you could use `netstat -an | egrep '^udp|LISTEN'` to include UDP, but that's rather verbose (and you'll also see quite a bit of nonsense UDP stuff, since there isn't really a concept of UDP listening vs. other states).  If you need to know the program, you need to go to the `lsof` (list open files) command, and that requires root access to check processes you don't own. Try something like `sudo lsof -nPi -sTCP:LISTEN`

Edit: as @loic.jaouen pointed out in another answer, while OS X's `netstat` doesn't have a direct equivalent to the Linux's `-p` option, the `-v` (verbose) display does include the PID of the process, and you can get the program name from that with `ps`.

Answer (score 4):

*[@gordon-davisson](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/427/gordon-davisson) is right, but you can still get the `pid` from `netstat` on mac with the verbove option. I post an answer as I lack the reputation to comment his answer.*

---

So, if the question is how to get `pid` and `port` in a `netstat` command, you can still do:

`netstat -anv`

the verbose option gives the `pid` in postition 9 like this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)     rhiwat shiwat    pid   epid
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.3335         *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072  45710      0
```

But the output is plethoric, which is bearable if you know what you look for, like: `netstat -anv | grep 3335` or `netstat -anv | grep LISTEN`

The output of `lsof` is still nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You can let your Mac "listen" on a network interface:

Type `sudo tcpdump -i en0` (followed by your administrator password)